# Values not getting passed from ascx codebehind to javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, smtp, ascx

I am using this to transfer values from ascx codebehind to ascx user control which has 3 Labels

```
 string text1 = fr.data[0].name;
        string text2 = m.data[0].name;
        string text3 = m.data[0].name;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), " ", "document.getElementById('lblfriend').innerHTML ='" + text1 + "'; return true;", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), " ", "document.getElementById('lblmyname').innerHTML ='" + text2 + "'; return true;", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), " ", "document.getElementById('lblmyname1').innerHTML ='" + text3 + "'; return true;", true);
```

**However values aren't getting passed and i want to render those Labels as Html so that they can be embedded in an email**

Please help!

Comment: what is your problem , are you getting data by fr.data[0].name, m.data[0].name?   Or you have problem with Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock code?

Comment: One problem is all the RegisterClientScriptBlock calls use the same Key so only the first is actually registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose the label text as string properties in the codebehind of the UserControl. Then when you render the usercontrol, pass the values to it and it would render the text of the labels.

Codebehind for the UserControl:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string _Friend;

    public string Friend
    {
        get
        {
            return _Friend;
        }
        set
        {
            _Friend = value;
            lblfriend.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private string _MyName;

    public string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyName;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyName = value;
            lblmyname.Text = value;
            lblmyname1.Text = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could load your values as such in your parent control/page:

```
        string text1 = fr.data[0].name;
        string text2 = m.data[0].name;                    
        MyUserControl.Friend = text1;
        MyUserControl.MyName = text2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the rendered page, are you sure your controls are named `lblFriend` and so on, I'm assuming they have a little more to it than that.

You may need to use

```
"document.getElementById('" + lblfriend.ClientID + "').innerHTML ='
```

Comment: yes the name are the same and now i can see the values however when i access this usercontrol on an aspx page converting it into html i cannot access the text in the Label it doesnt get displayed 
`  StringBuilder htmlResponse = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(htmlResponse))
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)){Control emailBody = Page.LoadControl("myEmailtemplate.ascx");
 emailBody.RenderControl(textWriter);
 emailHtml = htmlResponse.ToString();
 Session["emailHtml"] = emailHtml;
  }
        }

`

Comment: The values arent getting passed as text to the Asp.net label

Answer (score 0):

Write only one RegisterClientScript with control's ClientID
e.g.

```
String.Format(Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), " ", "document.getElementById('{0}').innerHTML ='" + text1 + "'; document.getElementById('{1}').innerHTML ='" + text2 + "';document.getElementById('{2}').innerHTML ='" + text3 + "'; return true;", true),lblfriend.ClientID,lblmyname.ClientID,lblmyname1.ClientID);
```

Or

```
String.Format(Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), " ", "{3}('{0}').{4} ='{5}'; {3}('{1}').{4}='{6}';{3}('{2}').{4}='{7}'; return true;", true),lblfriend.ClientID,lblmyname.ClientID,lblmyname1.ClientID,"document.getElementById","innerHTML",text1,text2,text3);
```

Comment: sorry for the syntax error, I've modifed it , please check now